# How to package a SharedAddin to ClickOnce deployment

Tags: .net

We have a shared Addin for Excel and want to go for ClickOnce deployment.
As we know it generates the MSI file when we setup a shared addin project, i am not sure how to package this... help me

Answer (score 0):

There is a great article about how to do this [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb821233.aspx)

This walks you through the whole process step by step.